# Convert opencv Mat to PyObject*

Tags: python, c++, opencv, pythonanywhere, python-embedding

I've tried to convert OpenCV `Mat` to `PyObject*` with this code :

```
PyObject* ConvertMatToPyArray(const cv::Mat& mat) {

    npy_intp dims[3] = { mat.rows, mat.cols, mat.channels() };
    const int ND = 3;
    PyObject *pArray = PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(
        ND, dims, NPY_UINT8, reinterpret_cast<void*>(mat.data));

    return pArray;
}
```

but always raise this exception :

```
Exception thrown at 0x00007FF75B5EDF03 in EmbededPython.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000010.
```

Where I mistake? or How can I convert Mat to PyObject* ?

In the beginning of my code I used :

```
Py_Initialize();
PySys_SetArgv(argc,(wchar_t**)argv);
```

But when I want to add `import_array()` this error occurred:

```
RuntimeError: _ARRAY_API is not PyCapsule object
```